# How to modify PATH in GNU Make and perform commands with $(shell ...) successfully?

Tags: shell, makefile, path, gnu-make

Background: I am having a customized toolchain which shall be used by a Makefile. The toolchain is checkout out (by svn:externals) into the working copy of the project. The Makefile must adapt the `PATH` Variable. Otherwise the toolchain-binaries cannot be found. Adapting the ´PATH´ in ´.bashrc´ or ´.profile´ is no option because there are several projects using different versions of the toolchain.

See this little minimal Makefile demonstrating the call to the cross compiler ´cc´ which is located next to several other tools in ´/home/edeviser/bin´:

```
export PATH:=/home/edeviser/bin:$(PATH)$
$(info Compiler used: $(shell which cc))

all:
    @echo "Compiler used: $(shell which cc)"
    @echo -n "Compiler used: "
    @which cc
```

The output after calling `make`:

```
Compiler used: /usr/bin/cc
Compiler used: /usr/bin/cc
Compiler used: /home/edeviser/bin/cc
```

My expectation is:

```
Compiler used: /home/edeviser/bin/cc
Compiler used: /home/edeviser/bin/cc
Compiler used: /home/edeviser/bin/cc
```

**How to modify PATH in GNU Make and perform commands with $(shell ...) successfully?**

Comment: `export` in make does not export into executed shell or commands in recipes. It exports variables into sub-make(s).

Comment: Oh, I did not know about that. But I wonder that it is working in one case, which is NOT executed in a sub-make call.

Comment: That is because the last invocation runs in an extra process (the shell) which DOES receive the modified environment from make. IMHO the environment not modified for the running process itself must be some remnant from ye olde times as it is a quite puzzling and strange inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a `shell` invocation like this:

```
$(info Compiler used: $(shell PATH='$(PATH)' which cc))
```

to set the PATH in the shell function.